# In Javascript, how to display the function body of a setter/getter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setter, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

For example (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), I init an object like this:

```
var o = {
  set current (str) {
    this.log[this.log.length] = str;
  },
  log: []
}
```

How can I print the function body of `o.current` in console? If `o.current` is a plain method, it can be done by `o.current.toString()`.. However, I have no idea about how to print the function body of a "getter" or "[setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)" method.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: you could simply use `o.toSource()` and then just extract the setter code out of the string that is returned? There must be a nicer way to do it though...

Comment: @k-nut `o.toSource()` doesn't work in my Chrome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__lookupSetter__` for this. So simply calling `o.__lookupSetter__('current').toString()`
should give you your desired output. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupSetter__)

**Update**

This is already deprecated though. You should be using the standard `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` instead. So calling `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'current').set.toString()`  will work for your use case. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)